# CS50 Pset1 Cash Example Wrong Output for 0.01 and 0.15

Tags: c, cs50

CS50 PSET1 CASH Example

Trying to get proper result for the input 0.01 and 0.15 but output results in "0" instead 1 and 2.

Code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    int cents,coins;


    do
    {
    float dollars = get_float("Change owed:");
    cents = roundf(dollars*100);
    }
    while(cents < 0);
    
    
while (cents/25 != 0)
{
    coins = cents/25;
    cents= cents%25;
    coins = coins + cents/10;
    cents = cents%10;
    coins = coins + cents/5;
    cents = cents%5;
    coins = coins + cents/1;
    cents = cents%1;   
}
printf("%i\n",coins);
}
```

Output:

:) cash.c exists
:) cash.c compiles
:) input of 0.41 yields output of 4
:( input of 0.01 yields output of 1
expected "1\n", not "32767\n"
:( input of 0.15 yields output of 2
expected "2\n", not "32767\n"
:) input of 1.6 yields output of 7
:) input of 23 yields output of 92
:) input of 4.2 yields output of 18
:) rejects a negative input like -1
:) rejects a non-numeric input of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric input of ""

Comment: At which point in your program do variabls start containing different values than you expect? How much debugging did you do?

Comment: After 0.3 everything works normally. But as the answer from @mikeCat without loop works fine.

Comment: You misunderstood. At what point within the failing testcase "0.01" do you start seeing unexpected values? (Not from which input test value. By the way I expect it to already work from 0.25 or 0.26.)

Comment: Didn't know anything about debugging. So it took me a while to figure out where it got wrong. It skips the while loop so gets a "0" value. But the question is why does it skip it? Cents/25!= 0 is must be TRUE? While cents is "1" so 1/25!= 0 is TRUE isn't it?

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks for the clarifications and being a good teacher! I'm new to the platform so it was a good example of how to behave :). Danke dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation for `coins` is not done when the input is less than 25 cents due to the `while` statment. *Undefined behavior* is invoked in this case due to usage of an (indeterminate) value of uninitialized non-static local varaible.

`cents` will become zero and the loop is meaningless, so you should remove the meangless and harmful loop.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
    int cents,coins;


    do
    {
        float dollars = get_float("Change owed:");
        cents = roundf(dollars*100);
    }
    while(cents < 0);
    
    
    /* remove this loop */
#if 0
    while (cents/25 != 0)
    {
#endif
        coins = cents/25;
        cents= cents%25;
        coins = coins + cents/10;
        cents = cents%10;
        coins = coins + cents/5;
        cents = cents%5;
        coins = coins + cents/1;
        cents = cents%1;
    /* remove this loop */
#if 0
    }
#endif
    printf("%i\n",coins);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike! Don't know why I thought loop is necessary!  
But isn't 1/25 !=0 is TRUE?

Comment: I am afraid OP accepted this as "code works as required" but would benefit from much additional explaining....